# What is "Error: SQL error: input of anonymous composite types is not implemented " in postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql

Would it be possible to know what is the meaning of this error `"error: SQL error: input of anonymous composite types is not implemented"`

I am getting the above error(`"error: SQL error: input of anonymous composite types is not implemented"`) when I perform the below query,

```
select *
from dev d
where not exists (select *
                  from ( 
                    select * 
                    from jsonb_array_elements_text(d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId')
                    where jsonb_typeof(d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId') = 'array'
                    and d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId' is not null
                    union all
                    select d.json_id ->> 'sourcedepartmentId'
                    where jsonb_typeof(d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId') = 'string'
                    and d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId' is not null
                  )  as jdata
                  where jdata in (  '109ec13a-46bd-26fe-6b1f-c4f329c76fda', 
                                    'fcf6f607-54f7-4e7c-8a42-23b66091a435', 
                                    '2dd35f81-27ce-55eb-bd3e-e46be3a378c4', 
                                    '1b381823-1df1-4ced-8b66-baad6e2456ee' )
                  )
```

`d.json_id -> 'sourcedepartmentId'` would have values as below,

- with just one uuid value. Example: `["ba18e414-92d3-446b-91b4-67050f891121"]` or
- multiple uuid values as an array. Example: `["45b90b79-1151-4d8c-8785-4886607524bd", "70b9de47-5e10-42a5-bf30-81c0d4efe6bd", "e1f30960-06eb-41b4-9ca7-49b389defcab", "5cb85419-7fb7-45bd-ae8c-46b3d7ab9154"]` or
- null or empty value.

Extract of the Table schema for the table named `dev`,

| dev id | Employee Name | JSON ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ef7fd5df-7881-470d-bc7d-846211df0344 | Tom | {"sourcedevIds":[],"sourcedepartmentId":["45b90b79-3457-4d8c-8567-4886602367bd"]} |
| 345r34-2345-56yt-78ui-343trtrfg567 | John | {"sourcedevIds":["wedfrtg-3456-3trr-6887-rte45R3"],"sourcedepartmentId":["45b90b79-1050-4d8c-8785-4886607524bd", "70b9de23-5e12-42a5-bf30-81c0d4efe6bd", "e1f30950-06eb-41b4-9ca7-49b456defcab", "5cb84516-7fb7-23bd-ae8c-46b3d7ab3467"]} |

|345r34-2345-56yt-78ui-343trtrfg567  | Brian        | {"sourcedevIds":["wedfrtg-7890-3trr-6887-rte45R3"],"sourcedepartmentId":[]}|

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Sorry, no. I made that mistake here. Tnx for pointing it out

Comment: What exactly is the `...`? Please share a [mcve] that we could e.g. paste into [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) to get the same error. I'd guess that `jdata` is the "composite type" (from `select *`) and that the `...` contains some untyped input parameters.

Comment: The error seems to be in the ellipsis.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the question. Please let me know if you need more information.  `where jdata in` will have a list of UUID values as shown above. Thanks

Comment: @jaesonBernardsha ah, yes, looks like a type mismatch to me. I think you'd get a better error message if you try explicit `where jdata in ('109ec36a-42bd-42fe-9b1f-c4f479c48fda'::text, …`. Hint: the type of `jdata` is not `text`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. Tried that and got the error `operator does not exist: record = text`.

Comment: @JSONB Good (to see my suspicion confirmed). Do you understand why that is?

Comment: @Bergi I am not sure actually. But the below-suggested answer seems to have worked by adding a column alias. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"jdata" is a table alias, not a column alias.  You should assign a column alias, and then use it.  Using a table alias as if it were a column name is possible, but it is not what you want here and is treated as a composite type.

```
...) as jdata(col1)
where col1 in (...
```

Of course it would be better to assign a meaningful alias not just "col1".